# Trigger on calculated date on Google AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, google-app-maker

I have function called `alertnotice(to, message, body)` that will be executed on a user `onClick()` event. The function will execute `sendEmail(to, message, body)` to send the email base on a calculated trigger as in variable `triggerDay` such as below:

```
function alertnotice(to, subject, body, dueDate, notifyBeforeDay) {//start of this class

  function sendEmail(to, subject, body){
    try {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: to,
        subject: subject,
        htmlBody: body
      });
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(JSON.stringify(e));
    }
  }

  //check if there is an existing trigger for this process
  var existingTrigger = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("sendEmailTrigger");

  //set the renewal notice day
  var triggerDay = (dueDate - notifyBeforeDay) / (1000*60*60*24);

  //if the trigger already exists, inform user about it
  if(existingTrigger) {

    return "Alert notice had been sent"; 

  } else { // if the trigger does not exists, continue to set the trigger to send alert notice

    //runs the script every day at 1am on the time zone specified
    var newTrigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmail')
    .timeBased()
    .atTime(triggerDay)
    .create();

    var triggerId = newTrigger.getUniqueId(); 

    if(triggerId) {
      PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("autoExportTrigger", triggerId);
      return "Alert notice send successfully!";
    } else {
      return "Failed to send alert notice. Try again please"; 
    }
 }

}//end of this class
```

So for example, if the dueDate is **30/07/2018** and the `notifyBeforeDay = 30`, the function should send the email 30 days before the due date. I tried to achieve that but not so sure whether my algorithm will work. Can anyone give advice on this?

Comment: Is this trigger separate for separate user or there will be single trigger only?

Comment: a single trigger for each user .. does my trigger correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implementation looks fragile to me. I would rather go with single trigger to avoid any possible duplicated emails and ensure at least one. Smth like this:

```javascript
// I am server script, trigger me on schedule (for instance nightly)
function sendAlerts() {
  var query = app.models.Customers.newQuery();

  // query only for non-notified customers with upcoming due date
  query.filters.NorificationAttempts._lessThan = ATTEMPTS_THRESHOLD;
  query.filters.Notified._equals = false;
  query.filters.DueDate._lessThan = <dueDate>;

  var customers = query.run();

  customers.forEach(function(customer) {
    var success = sendNotification(customer);

    if (success) {
      customer.Notified = true;
    } else {
      customer.NorificationAttempts++;
    }

    // performance trade off in favor of consistency
    app.saveRecords([customer]);
  });
}
```

Trigger for such script can be installed by app's admin, you can find similar implementation in [People Skills](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/templates/people-skills/) template.

Comment: this is if my case is the sendEmail() function right?

Comment: Kinda yes... it is just a function that you need to feed to a trigger and in your original code snippet you are passing to the trigger `sendEmail` function.

Comment: what to fill in <dueDate> ?

Comment: Smth like this: `var today = new Date(); var expiresOn = new Date(); tomorrow.setDate(today.getDate() + notificationThreshold); query.filters.DueDate._lessThan = expiresOn;`

Comment: tried that one but got this error : InternalError: Cannot find method at(number). at alertnotice (SendEmailTrigger:97) at SendEmailTrigger:125 at sendAlerts (SendEmailTrigger:124) at onProjectCreate_ (Datasources:64) at models.Project.onBeforeCreateEvent:1